# Errors in trying to makefile?

Tags: c, bash, shell, makefile

I downloaded [the NIST (Pseudo)randomness Test Suite](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/sts-2.1.1.zip) and was trying to `./makefile` it in my Mac OS terminal. However, I encountered the following error messages.

```
v1020-wn-236-94:sts-2.1 Eric$ ./makefile
clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
./makefile: line 2: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 3: ROOTDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 4: ROOTDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 4: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 5: ROOTDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 5: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 6: VPATH: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 8: OBJ: command not found
./makefile: line 18: OBJ: command not found
./makefile: line 18: assess:: command not found
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 19: OBJ: command not found
./makefile: line 19: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 21: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 21: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 21: /assess.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 22: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 22: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 24: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 24: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 24: /frequency.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 25: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 25: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 25: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 27: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 27: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 27: /blockFrequency.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 28: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 28: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 28: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 30: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 30: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 30: /cusum.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 31: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 31: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 31: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 33: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 33: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 33: /runs.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 34: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 34: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 34: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 36: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 36: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 36: /longestRunOfOnes.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 37: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 37: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 37: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 39: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 39: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 39: /rank.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 40: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 40: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 40: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 42: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 42: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 42: /discreteFourierTransform.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 44: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 44: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 44: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 47: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 47: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 47: /nonOverlappingTemplateMatchings.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 48: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 48: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 48: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 51: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 51: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 51: /overlappingTemplateMatchings.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 52: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 52: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 52: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 54: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 54: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 54: /universal.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 55: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 55: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 55: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 57: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 57: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 57: /approximateEntropy.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 58: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 58: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 58: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 60: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 60: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 60: /randomExcursions.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 61: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 61: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 61: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 63: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 63: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 63: /randomExcursionsVariant.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 64: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 64: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 64: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 66: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 66: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 66: /serial.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 67: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 67: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 67: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 69: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 69: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 69: /linearComplexity.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 70: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 70: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 70: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 72: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 72: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 72: /dfft.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 73: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 73: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 73: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 75: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 75: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 75: /matrix.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 76: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 76: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 76: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 78: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 78: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 78: /genutils.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 79: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 79: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 79: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 81: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 81: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 81: /cephes.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 82: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 82: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 82: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 84: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 84: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 84: /utilities.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 85: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 85: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 85: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 87: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 87: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 87: /generators.o:: No such file or directory
clang: error: no input files
./makefile: line 89: GCCFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 89: SRCDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 89: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 91: clean:: command not found
./makefile: line 92: OBJDIR: command not found
./makefile: line 94: rebuild:: command not found
```

**I believe I have the right gcc directory and `ROOTDIR`. My makefile file is as follows.**

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
GCCFLAGS = -c -Wall
ROOTDIR = /Users/Eric/Desktop/sts-2.1
SRCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/src
OBJDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/obj
VPATH  = src:obj:include

OBJ = $(OBJDIR)/assess.o $(OBJDIR)/frequency.o $(OBJDIR)/blockFrequency.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/cusum.o $(OBJDIR)/runs.o $(OBJDIR)/longestRunOfOnes.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/serial.o $(OBJDIR)/rank.o $(OBJDIR)/discreteFourierTransform.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/nonOverlappingTemplateMatchings.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/overlappingTemplateMatchings.o $(OBJDIR)/universal.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/approximateEntropy.o $(OBJDIR)/randomExcursions.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/randomExcursionsVariant.o $(OBJDIR)/linearComplexity.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/dfft.o $(OBJDIR)/cephes.o $(OBJDIR)/matrix.o \
      $(OBJDIR)/utilities.o $(OBJDIR)/generators.o $(OBJDIR)/genutils.o

assess: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) -lm

$(OBJDIR)/assess.o: $(SRCDIR)/assess.c defs.h decls.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $(SRCDIR)/assess.c

$(OBJDIR)/frequency.o: $(SRCDIR)/frequency.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/frequency.c

$(OBJDIR)/blockFrequency.o: $(SRCDIR)/blockFrequency.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/blockFrequency.c

$(OBJDIR)/cusum.o: $(SRCDIR)/cusum.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/cusum.c

$(OBJDIR)/runs.o: $(SRCDIR)/runs.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/runs.c

$(OBJDIR)/longestRunOfOnes.o: $(SRCDIR)/longestRunOfOnes.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/longestRunOfOnes.c

$(OBJDIR)/rank.o: $(SRCDIR)/rank.c defs.h externs.h matrix.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/rank.c

$(OBJDIR)/discreteFourierTransform.o: $(SRCDIR)/discreteFourierTransform.c \
        defs.h externs.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/discreteFourierTransform.c

$(OBJDIR)/nonOverlappingTemplateMatchings.o: \
        $(SRCDIR)/nonOverlappingTemplateMatchings.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/nonOverlappingTemplateMatchings.c

$(OBJDIR)/overlappingTemplateMatchings.o: \
        $(SRCDIR)/overlappingTemplateMatchings.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/overlappingTemplateMatchings.c

$(OBJDIR)/universal.o: $(SRCDIR)/universal.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/universal.c

$(OBJDIR)/approximateEntropy.o: $(SRCDIR)/approximateEntropy.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/approximateEntropy.c

$(OBJDIR)/randomExcursions.o: $(SRCDIR)/randomExcursions.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/randomExcursions.c

$(OBJDIR)/randomExcursionsVariant.o: $(SRCDIR)/randomExcursionsVariant.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/randomExcursionsVariant.c

$(OBJDIR)/serial.o: $(SRCDIR)/serial.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/serial.c

$(OBJDIR)/linearComplexity.o: $(SRCDIR)/linearComplexity.c defs.h externs.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/linearComplexity.c

$(OBJDIR)/dfft.o: $(SRCDIR)/dfft.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/dfft.c

$(OBJDIR)/matrix.o: $(SRCDIR)/matrix.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h matrix.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/matrix.c

$(OBJDIR)/genutils.o: $(SRCDIR)/genutils.c config.h genutils.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/genutils.c

$(OBJDIR)/cephes.o: $(SRCDIR)/cephes.c cephes.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/cephes.c

$(OBJDIR)/utilities.o: $(SRCDIR)/utilities.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h config.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/utilities.c

$(OBJDIR)/generators.o: $(SRCDIR)/generators.c defs.h externs.h utilities.h \
        config.h generators.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $(GCCFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/generators.c

clean:
    rm -f assess $(OBJDIR)/*.o

rebuild: clean assess
```

**How may I fix this and continue?**

Comment: makefile is consumed by the make utility, not executed.  Just type `make` in that dir, it will pick up the makefile and do what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

See this [make tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/). It explains everything about make utility and how it compiles according to the dependencies and rules defined in the makefile.